# How can I set 664 (or custom) permission on files created or rotated with rails Logger.new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

As the title states, how can I control what permissions are used on log files when rails creates (and rotates) them using `Logger.new`?

In my case, the parent `log` folder has 777 permissions, and is owned by an account with sudo access. My rails app runs as `www-data` and I have other jobs like delayed jobs and cron tasks that run in the same app directory, and they run as another user with sudo access. I'm noticing that some files are being created with insufficient privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colleague pointed out that this can be done a lot more easily, by setting the File.umask for the current process, as follows

```
# Set the umask so the logs are group write-able
File.umask(2)
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-umask

Answer (score 2):

After reading the [source of the stdlib implementation of `Logger`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/lib/logger.rb), I think that you'll need to create a custom class (or to monkey-patch the default implementation).

My first proposition (see below) was to manually create a file with the correct permissions and then to create the `Logger` using this file instead of just a path string. However, it turns out that this doesn't work if you want to use rotation (for multiple reasons).

Here's a solution that seems to work:

`Logger` internally uses a `Logger::LogDevice`. This object handles the creation and rotation of the log files. However, you can't choose the permissions used for the new files. My proposition is to create a custom `LogDevice` that will handles file permissions:

```
class CustomLogDevice < Logger::LogDevice
  def create_logfile(filename)
    super.tap {|f| f.chmod(0664) }
  end
end

log_device = CustomLogDevice.new("file.log", shift_age: 'daily')
logger = Logger.new(log_device)
```

**Notes:**
This custom `LogDevice` is very basic, you might want to do something more elaborated. You can find the default implementation [on GitHub](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/lib/logger.rb#L535) for reference.

Rotation options must be passed to the `LogDevice`, not the `Logger`. The keys are `:shift_age` and `:shift_size`

---

### Previous answer

[`Logger.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-c-new) first argument can be a filename (String), but also an IO object (typically STDOUT, STDERR, or an open file).

[`File.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-new) (and [`File.open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-open) that is mostly equivalent) accept permission bits as an an optional third argument: `new(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt])`

So this should work

```
log_file = File.open("path/to/file.log", "a", 0664)
logger = Logger.new(log_file)
```

**Notes:**
The specified permissions will only applied if a new file is created, not when opening an existing file.

The *mode* `"a"` is an alias for `File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT`
(write-only, starts at end of file if file exists, otherwise creates a new file for writing).
See [`IO.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-new) for more informations.

The permission bits (here `0644`) must start with a `0`. This indicates Ruby that they are in octal notation, not decimal.

Comment: Gregoire, thanks. I will test this, but it doesn't look like this will help if I'm telling Logger to also rotate the log?

Comment: Damn, you are right! I shouldn't have overlooked that part. I just took a look at the source and it looks like this can't be done without monkey-patching the stdlib implementation.

Comment: @ShyamHabarakada I updated my answer with something that should work.

Comment: Yup that should work. I also looked into this and got to LogDevice, and for my own implementation, held off on monkey patching it.

Comment: Also, this seems like a bug in the default rails logger. If I manually set permissions on the file, when it is rotated, the new file does not seem to get the same permissions. In unix log rotate, this is standard behavior, so I would expect the ruby implementation to do the same. If someone gets around to opening a bug on this against ruby, let me know. Otherwise, I will try to get around to it.

Comment: Turns out there is a much simpler solution to this, assuming you are okay with all files created by the rails app having the same default permissions. See new answer added here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24639229/850996